# Group time-indexed DataFrame by arbitrary intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` df as follows:

```
Time    Student
9:29    Alex
9:32    Bob
9:34    Carrie
9:41    Donald
9:48    Elijah
9:49    Fred
9:53    George
10:02   Henry
10:07   Ian
```

And a list `list = [9:34, 9:41, 9:45, 9:57]`.

My desired output is to have a `dataframe2` which looks like this

```
Time2         Students
< first time  Alex     Bob     Carrie
9:34          Donald
9:41    
9:45          Elijah   Fred    George
9:57          all other students
```

Basically, using the elements in `list`, I aim to group all the students into bins where each bin[i] contains all `x in list[i] < x <= list[i+1]`. Also, all students coming in before the first and after the last element in `list` should be put into the special bins as seen in `dataframe2`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.grouper`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq = '10Min'))['Student'].\
                                 apply(lambda x: list(x)).\
                                 reset_index()
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time
```

Output:

```
       Time                 Student
0  09:20:00                  [Alex]
1  09:30:00           [Bob, Carrie]
2  09:40:00  [Donald, Elijah, Fred]
3  09:50:00                [George]
4  10:00:00            [Henry, Ian]
```

### EDIT:

In case you have irregular time intervals such as the list of intervals (`list = [9:34, 9:41, 9:45, 9:57]`) you provided, the following method may be used. I personally am not aware of a more concise method!

```
ls = ['9:34', '9:41', '9:45', '9:57']

## A "last-call" time for the day. Note that this method fails if any student features after this time (23:59:59):
ls.append('23:59:59')
ls = pd.DatetimeIndex(ls).time

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time

def idx_getter(t, ls):
    """
    Returns the right hand side of the interval the timestamp falls in.
    """
    return ls[sum(t > ls)]

df['time_grp'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda t: idx_getter(t, ls))
std_grps = pd.Series(ls).\
             map(df.groupby('time_grp')['Student'].apply(list))
std_grps.index = ls

std_grps
```

OUTPUT:

```
09:34:00       [Alex, Bob, Carrie]
09:41:00                  [Donald]
09:45:00                       NaN
09:57:00    [Elijah, Fred, George]
23:59:59              [Henry, Ian]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I do not think I can do that as Time2 values are arbitrary in real life (if it makes sense), so the intervals are not regular.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - I thought you said there would be 10 minute intervals and you were interested in finding sets of students who featured within each such interval. Could you give me an example of a case where this wouldn't work?

Comment: I'm sorry for being misleading - edited the main post!

Comment: So there's no structure to the interval lengths?

Comment: Is there a way to use a timestamp that is sensitive up to milliseconds for this, i.e. ''09:30:00.020"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```
lst = ['9:34', '9:41', '9:45', '9:57']
```

```
breaks = [-np.inf, *(pd.to_datetime(lst)).astype(np.int64) // 10e9, np.inf]
labels = [f'<{lst[0]}', *lst]

v = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).astype(np.int64) // 10e9
cats = pd.cut(v, bins=breaks, labels=labels, right=True)

df.groupby(cats).Student.agg(', '.join)
```

```
Time
<9:34       Alex, Bob, Carrie
9:34                   Donald
9:41                     None
9:45     Elijah, Fred, George
9:57               Henry, Ian
Name: Student, dtype: object
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I think this method works, but what if the elements in `lst` goes up to milliseconds? I used `breaks = [-np.inf, *(pd.to_datetime(list, format='%H:%M:%S %f')).astype(np.int64) // 10e9, np.inf]` but the values in  `breaks` were the same for all elements in `lst`

Comment: @AdrianY Sorry, the context switching takes some time. I don't know what it'd take to take your incremental requirements into account without more context.  It wasn't a requirement in your original question, so can you open a new one?